# Create a duplicate of a folder and the folders in it, while changing their names

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.path

I'm trying to create an output folder/file for a batch script I'm running on every file in a folder. I would like it if when I found all the files or folders in the targetFolder I could create a targetFolder_output, and if targetFolder has a folder, anotherFolder, in it I could create anotherFolder_output in targetFolder_out.

So in the end I have C:\targetFolder\anotherFolder and it's duplicate C:\targetFolder_output\anotherFolder_output

I plan to do this with all of the files in there, but I think if I can get over this folder hurdle, I can handle the file one.

```
import os

targetFolder = "C:\\Users\\MyUserName\\Desktop\\tests"
outputFolder = targetFolder + "_output"

# Iterate over everything in the targetFolder
for directory, subdirectories, files in os.walk(targetFolder): 
    folderBasename = (os.path.basename(directory) )

    if not os.path.exists(outputFolder + "\\" + folderBasename + "_output"):
        os.makedirs(outputFolder + "\\" + folderBasename + "_output")
```

So far all this is doing is making a folder on my desktop "tests_output" with the folders:

tests_output\tests_output

tests_output\level2_output

tests_output\level3_output

What I would like to see is:

tests_output\level2_output\level3_output

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: it's always better to use `os.path.join()` than glueing paths manually.

Comment: Good to know, and would probably save me a lot of headache later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
class FCopy(object):
    def __init__(self, source):
        self.source = source
        self.target = os.path.join(source, '_output')
        if not os.path.exists(self.target):
            os.makedirs(os.path.abspath(self.target))
        self.lf, self.ld = [], []

    def walk(self, path):
        for x in (os.path.join(path, x) for x in os.listdir(path)):
            if x == self.target:continue
            if os.path.isfile(x):
                self.lf.append(x)
            elif os.path.isdir(x):
                self.ld.append(x)
                self.walk(x)
            #extra code if you want to handle symlinks

    def do(self):
        #if thats all you want,
        #code this directly in walk
        self.walk(self.source)

        for x in self.ld:
            x = x.replace(self.source, self.target)
            os.makedirs(x)
        for x in self.lf:
            x = x.replace(self.source, self.target)
            with open(x, 'w') as f:pass

f = FCopy('C:\\PerfLogs\\w\\tmp\\codemirror')
f.do()
```

You may play with ifexists and so on.
If all you want is double the structure of source, then you could move the creation of files/dirs in walk, in corresponding if...else
P.S.: ignore my dir, I just make a test in it

Comment: I'm away from my computer right this moment, but as soon as I get a chance I will certainly check this out to see if its what I need! I'm in my phone right now so I can only see so much, but it looks promising! Thank you!

Comment: If you don't want files created - I think you don't - comment/delete for x in self.lf and the 2 lines after from do()

Comment: Sorry about to long delay, but I finally got to test the code. So what your is doing, when I set `FCopy('C:\\Users\\Hobo\\Desktop\\tests')`, is creating a folder "_output" in the tests folder, with a level2 folder inside that, with a level3 folder inside of that. What I am trying to do is make a folder "tests_output" on the desktop, with each folder in that having "_output" appended to it as well. What you have given me is still really helpful! I think I can make it work from here, if nothing else!

Comment: Just change the target - that's the main reason I putt everithing in a class. I thought you want an replica of a folder structure - that's why it create an empty file to.